# net core 3 web service connection problem

Tags: wcf, soap, .net-core, httpclient, soap-client

I am trying to connect a web service and getting below error message.

```
An error occurred while sending the request.

Error 12002 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The operation timed out'.
```

using net standart library and net core 3.1 console application. Something wrong with httpclient connection timeout but I could not figure it out how to resolve it.

code example :

```
            FirmboxSoapClient soapClient = new FirmboxSoapClient(FirmboxSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.FirmboxSoap);
            await soapClient.OpenAsync();
            var response =  await soapClient.loginAsync("USER_NAME", "PASSWORD", "Version", false);
```

After updated the package error turn into

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Is the service endpoint address corresponding to FirmboxSoap enum an Https address? Can you post the address? It might be the server issue. Https connection requires the client/server-side support. Besides, can you call the service in a DotNet Framework project properly?

Comment: @AbrahamQian I will try it in a .net framework today. I let you know. And also waiting for relpy from service provider

Comment: @AbrahamQian problem was solved. It was related to service provider.